# Packrat parsing (memoization via laziness) in OCaml

Tags: parsing, functional-programming, ocaml, lazy-evaluation, memoization

I'm implementing a packrat parser in OCaml, as per the [Master Thesis by B. Ford.](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~baford/packrat/thesis/)  My parser should receive a data structure that represents the grammar of a language and parse given sequences of symbols.

I'm stuck with the memoization part.  The original thesis uses Haskell's lazy evaluation to accomplish linear time complexity.  I want to do this (memoization via laziness) in OCaml, but don't know how to do it.

So, how do you memoize functions by lazy evaluations in OCaml?

EDIT: I know what lazy evaluation is and how to exploit it in OCaml.  The question is how to use it to memoize functions.

EDIT: The data structure I wrote that represents grammars is:

```
type ('a, 'b, 'c) expr =
| Empty of 'c
| Term of 'a * ('a -> 'c)
| NTerm of 'b
| Juxta of ('a, 'b, 'c) expr * ('a, 'b, 'c) expr * ('c -> 'c -> 'c)
| Alter of ('a, 'b, 'c) expr * ('a, 'b, 'c) expr
| Pred of ('a, 'b, 'c) expr * 'c
| NPred of ('a, 'b, 'c) expr * 'c
type ('a, 'b, 'c) grammar = ('a * ('a, 'b, 'c) expr) list
```

The (not-memoized) function that parse a list of symbols is:

```
let rec parse g v xs = parse' g (List.assoc v g) xs
and parse' g e xs =
  match e with
  | Empty y -> Parsed (y, xs)
  | Term (x, f) ->
     begin
       match xs with
       | x' :: xs when x = x' -> Parsed (f x, xs)
       | _ -> NoParse
     end
  | NTerm v' -> parse g v' xs
  | Juxta (e1, e2, f) ->
     begin
       match parse' g e1 xs with
       | Parsed (y, xs) ->
          begin
            match parse' g e2 xs with
            | Parsed (y', xs) -> Parsed (f y y', xs)
            | p -> p
          end
       | p -> p
     end
( and so on )
```

where the type of the return value of parse is defined by

```
type ('a, 'c) result = Parsed of 'c * ('a list) | NoParse
```

For example, the grammar of basic arithmetic expressions can be specified as `g`, in:

```
type nt = Add | Mult | Prim | Dec | Expr
let zero _  = 0
let g =
  [(Expr, Juxta (NTerm Add, Term ('$', zero), fun x _ -> x));
   (Add, Alter (Juxta (NTerm Mult, Juxta (Term ('+', zero), NTerm Add, fun _ x -> x), (+)), NTerm Mult));
   (Mult, Alter (Juxta (NTerm Prim, Juxta (Term ('*', zero), NTerm Mult, fun _ x -> x), ( * )), NTerm Prim));
   (Prim, Alter (Juxta (Term ('<', zero), Juxta (NTerm Dec, Term ('>', zero), fun x _ -> x), fun _ x -> x), NTerm Dec));
   (Dec, List.fold_left (fun acc d -> Alter (Term (d, (fun c -> int_of_char c - 48)), acc)) (Term ('0', zero)) ['1';'2';'3';])]
```

Comment: I thought parckrat parsing is a well-known technique and so is its inventor's master's thesis.  But it seems it isn't :-)

Answer (score 6):

The idea of using lazyness for memoization is use not functions, but data structures, for memoization. Lazyness means that when you write `let x = foo in some_expr`, `foo` will not be evaluated immediately, but only as far as `some_expr` needs it, but that different occurences of `x`in `some_expr` will share the same trunk: as soon as one of them force computation, the result is available to all of them.

This does not work for functions: if you write `let f x = foo in some_expr`, and call `f` several times in `some_expr`, well, each call will be evaluated independently, there is not a shared thunk to store the results.

So you can get memoization by using a data structure instead of a function. Typically, this is done using an associative data structure: instead of computing a `a -> b` function, you compute a `Table a b`, where `Table` is some map from the arguments to the results. One example is this Haskell presentation of fibonacci:

```
fib n = fibTable !! n
fibTable = [0,1] ++ map (\n -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)) [2..]
```

(You can also write that with `tail` and `zip`, but this doesn't make the point clearer.)

See that you do not memoize a function, but a list: it is the list `fibTable` that does the memoization. You can write this in OCaml as well, for example using the LazyList module of the [Batteries](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/) library:

```
open Batteries
module LL = LazyList

let from_2 = LL.seq 2 ((+) 1) (fun _ -> true)

let rec fib n = LL.at fib_table (n - 1) + LL.at fib_table (n - 2)
and fib_table = lazy (LL.Cons (0, LL.cons 1 <| LL.map fib from_2))
```

However, there is little interest in doing so: as you have seen in the example above, OCaml does not particularly favor call-by-need evaluation -- it's reasonable to use, but not terribly convenient as it was forced to be in Haskell. It is actually equally simple to directly write the cache structure by direct mutation:

```
open Batteries

let fib =
  let fib_table = DynArray.of_list [0; 1] in
  let get_fib n = DynArray.get fib_table n in
  fun n ->
    for i = DynArray.length fib_table to n do
      DynArray.add fib_table (get_fib (i - 1) + get_fib (i - 2))
    done;
    get_fib n
```

This example may be ill-chosen, because you need a dynamic structure to store the cache. In the packrat parser case, you're tabulating parsing on a known input text, so you can use plain arrays (indexed by the grammar rules): you would have an array of `('a, 'c) result option` for each rule, of the size of the input length and initialized to `None`. Eg. `juxta.(n)` represents the result of trying the rule `Juxta` from input position `n`, or `None` if this has not yet been tried.

Lazyness is a nice way to present this kind of memoization, but is not always expressive enough: if you need, say, to partially free some part of your result cache to lower memory usage, you will have difficulties if you started from a lazy presentation. See [this blog post](http://awelonblue.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/windowed-memoization/) for a remark on this.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to memoize functions? What you want to memoize is, I believe, the parsing result for a given (parsing) expression and a given position in the input stream. You could for instance use Ocaml's Hashtables for that.

Answer (score 0):

The [lazy](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Lazy.html) keyword.

[Here](http://blog.enfranchisedmind.com/posts/ocaml-lazy-lists-an-introduction/) you can find some great examples.

If it fits your use case, you can also use OCaml streams instead of manually generating thunks.